# Track Session timeout when using stateserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, session-state

Is is possible to log when a session times out when a stateserver is used to manage session data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to write your own httpmodule and maintain and list of sessions which timeout after a certain time period

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Session.IsNewSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.isnewsession.aspx).

Comment: This only tells you if the Session associated with the current Request has been newly created during this request. I think fARcRY is looking for a way to be notified when a Session dies.